# How to unshadow a chosen definition for a function

Tags: packages, variable-definitions

I want to use the package [NCAlgebra](http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/). However after successfully installing the package and trying to write some code, basic functions like

```
SetNonCommutative[...]
```

is collored in red with the statement:

> A symbol occurs in more than one context: One of the definitions is shadowed.

How can I force *Mathematica* to use the function from the package?

Comment: Did you quit the kernel and then reload the package?

Comment: @JasonB Thanks this resolves the problem!

Comment: Glad to help Anne.

Answer (score 3):

Quitting and restarting may not always be the best way to handle shadowing, as it destroys the results of any computations performed.  One can also use [`Remove`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Remove.html).  From the tutorial [Contexts](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html)

> If you once introduce a symbol that shadows existing symbols, it will continue to do so until you either rearrange $ContextPath, or explicitly remove the symbol. You should realize that it is not sufficient to clear the value of the symbol; you need to actually remove the symbol completely from the Wolfram Language. You can do this using the function Remove[s].

Example.  First I `Quit[]` for a clean start.  I then define `foo`, which creates the symbol `` Global`foo ``.

```
Quit[]

foo = 1
(*  1  *)
```

Now let's say I load a package called `` "Foo`" ``, which creates its own variable `foo`.  Then the following two commands in effect happen somewhere along the way.

```
Foo`foo = 2
(*  2  *)

AppendTo[$ContextPath, "Foo`"]
(*
  {"StreamingLoader`", "IconizeLoader`", "CloudObjectLoader`", 
   "PacletManager`", "System`", "Global`", "Foo`"}
*)
```

At this point `foo` is shadowed and appears in red.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's say that `` Global`foo `` is unnecessary.  Then the following removes the shadowing.

```
Remove["Global`foo"]
```

The cells in which `foo` and `` Foo`foo `` appeared above now look like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Another alternative it is to live with the shadowing and always type `` Global`foo `` for one's own `foo`.  In a properly written package, internal references to the package's `foo` should always refer to `` Foo`foo ``.  Whether it is more convenient to type the context or remove the symbol and use a different, unshadowed variable name is up to the user.

---

Related Q&A:

- [Strategies for avoiding and handling shadowing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/312/strategies-for-avoiding-and-handling-shadowing)
- [Remove versus ClearAll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37624/remove-versus-clearall/)