# Cross referencing symbols in different packages

Tags: packages, scoping, contexts

I have problems with name space shadowing which I do not know how to resolve. I have two packages which depend on each other. Here is example of two files

**fooPackage.m:**

```
BeginPackage["fooPackage`",{"barPackage`"}];
top::usage = "This is top level funciton";
foo::usage = "Text";
Begin["Private`"];

top[arg___]:=bar[];
foo[arg___]:=Print["This is foo!"];

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

**barPackage.m:**

```
BeginPackage["barPackage`", {"fooPackage`"}];
bar::usage = "";
Begin["Private`"]

bar[arg___] := (Print["This is bar!"]; foo[arg])

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Now if I use it as I intended:

```
Quit[];

Needs["fooPackage`", "/home/johu/temp/fooPackage.m"]

top[]
$ContextPath[[;; 2]]
```

> ```
> This is bar!
> Private`foo[]
> {"fooPackage`", "barPackage`"}
> ```

I would get `bar` working if I loaded another package as top level which however does not contain the definition `top`

```
Quit[];

Needs["barPackage`", "/home/johu/temp/barPackage.m"]

bar[b]
top[b]
$ContextPath[[;; 2]]
```

> ```
> This is bar!
> This is foo!
> Private`bar[]
> {"barPackage`", "fooPackage`"}
> ```

My question is how to avoid this shadowing or what would be the cleanest workaround?

Perhaps you can also explain, why in the first case does it even make a name for local symbol `` Private`foo[] ``? It is never defined.

Here are some references to relevant educational sources, which however did not solve my confusion

- [Creating Mathematica packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29325/2036)
- [Setting Up Wolfram Language Packages](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html)
- [What are recommended guidelines for developing packages?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290/what-are-recommended-guidelines-for-developing-packages)
- [What's the difference between these two ways of specifying dependent packages?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-ways-of-specifying-dependent-packages?rq=1)

Comment: Actually, I just realized that this was asked already before. I will port this version of my answer to that post, which contains a less extensive one.

Comment: Yes, the discussion was very relevant. I exactly have the `mainPackage` & `helperPackage` issue. Solution 2 from the referred is the most acceptable one. I guess I should accept the `duplicate tag` then?

Comment: Good to know it helped. Re: accept - you don't have to do anything. If you want, you can become one of the closers for this question, by adding your vote to close this one as a duplicate (if you have the right to close questions, I don't remember how much rep it takes for that). If you feel like it, you can vote for that discussion question / answer. One thing though: please don't delete this one - it will serve as another gateway to that discussion.